# In Tritium, can I select all children of a node?

Tags: moovweb, tritium

I have a div that has several child divs. Some have ID's and classes, some do not.

I have used move_children_to() and was wondering if there is something similar to select the children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways to select the immediate children.

First you can do:

```
$("./*") {
  # code for children goes here.
}
move_children_to("..", "after)
```

Another way to handle this would be to just open a scope on `move_children_to()`

```
move_children_to("..", "after) {
  # children code can go here.
}
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if I can provide any more assistance.